# webpack-dev-server react-router push state

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am trying to get react-router to work with webpack-dev-server but keep getting cannot Get /SOMEURL. This is because webpack-dev-server is looking for that specific file but cannot find it. I'd like webpack to resort to using react-router vs searching for the files itself.

How can I set that up?

My grunt:

```
'webpack-dev-server': {
      options: {
        hot: true,
        port: 8000,
        webpack: webpackDevConfig,
        publicPath: '/assets/',
        contentBase: './<%= pkg.src %>/'
      },

      start: {
        keepAlive: true,
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `--history-api-fallback` option to `webpack-dev-server`. This uses [connect-history-api-fallback](https://github.com/bripkens/connect-history-api-fallback) to serve up `index.html` if the route doesn't match any other files. (This does mean you have to use `index.html` as the filename for your HTML page.)

Comment: That ended up always going to the DefaultRoute everytime rather than other routes I specified

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the routing setup, not webpack. Do you have code you can share?

Comment: Ended up solving with /#/

Comment: Nice answer, better save this configuration in `webpack.config.js`, just add `devServer: { historyApiFallback: true }` to `webpack.config.js`

Comment: similar issue, same solution
[Another SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35372798/3050426)

Comment: this works but not with react hot loader, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159965/enable-single-page-app-react-hot-reload-webpack

Answer (score 2):

For me, i had this in my index file:

```
<script src="./assets/app.js"></script>
```

rather than

```
 <script src="/assets/app.js"></script>
```

So, it looks like the history fallback API was in competition with
my misconfiguration.