# nested url routing using react-router and webpack dev server

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I'm having some issues working with react-router and webpack-dev-server to achieve nested url routing.

**webpack.config.js**

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    publicPath: "/", <-- this enabled routing to /register/step2
    filename: "js/bundle.js",
},
```

**routes.js**

```
const routes = {
    childRoutes: [
        { path: '/', component: Home },
        { path: '/login', component: Login },
        { path: '/register', component: Register },
        { path: '/register/step2', component: SecondStep },
    ]
};

export default (<Router routes={routes} history={createBrowserHistory()} />);
```

When clicking around in the appliation, I can get to /register/step2 but once I hit refresh in the browser, my common.js and bundle.js is missing: 404, since it's trying to load everything from /register/ directory.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out. 2 things that is needed to enable this.

webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true <-- this needs to be set to true
}
```

routes.js

```
const routes = {
    childRoutes: [
        { path: '/', component: Home },
        { path: '/login', component: Login },
        { path: '/register', component: Register, childRoutes: [
            { path: 'step2', component: SecondStep },
        ] },
    ]
};
```

Comment: historyApiFallback: true,  seems to solve the problem.. thanks

Comment: but not with hot reload: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40159965/enable-single-page-app-react-hot-reload-webpack

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your webpack configuration file contains following code:

```js
output: {
    publicPath: '/'
},
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```

See more [in this article](https://medium.com/fredwong-it/react-router-v4-nested-routes-not-work-with-webpack-dev-server-50a2cf32e46e)

Answer (score -1):

If you use hashHistory instead of createBrowserHistory() it will keep the server from requesting to your current url on your server.

```
export default (<Router routes={routes} history={hashHistory} />);
```

Comment: Is there not a way to achieve this without using hashes?

Comment: The guide at react-router recommends using browserHistory over hashHistory.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#createbrowserhistory