# React-Routing basic example path not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

Triyng for run basic example from [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic)

I've got Yarn+Webpack2+Babel es2015

This is my entry point:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

     const BasicExample = () => (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                    <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                </ul>

                <hr/>

                <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );

    const Home = () => (
        <div>
            <h2>Home</h2>
        </div>
    );

    const About = () => (
        <div>
            <h2>About</h2>
        </div>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(
        <BasicExample/>,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Project at http://localhost:8080 starting  good and Links working fine, rendering content from Home and About components.

But when I'm trying to enter url http://localhost:8080/about - console showing me

> GET http://localhost:8080/about 404 (Not Found)

I found many almost same questions on Stack, but not found solution working for me.
What exactly in react-router intercept incoming url?
It possible that this not working because of mine Yarn\Webpack settings?

____________**UPDATE_1**
Webpack config

```
const path = require('path');
let webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
    /*devServer: {
        host: "DESKTOP-A5FTMD8", // Can change port
        port: 8080
    },*/
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'index.jsx'),
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.(less|css)$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'},
            {test: /\.(xml)$/, loader: 'xml-loader'},
            {test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg)$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx|es6)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'react-hot-loader!babel-loader?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015'
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.es6']
    },
    plugins: [
        HtmlWebpackPluginConfig
    ]
};
```

Comment: It looks like a problem of your `webpack-dev-server` configuration.

Comment: Did you `npm install react-router-dom` / `yarn add react-router-dom`? Also check out my basic example here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/react-router/5546/getting-started-with-react-router/30504/getting-started#t=201705181158028254636

Comment: @toomuchdesign Added mine webpack config

Comment: @SventenHaaf, create from start app by your example. Result is the same.
Possibly **toomuchdesign** right about my webpack configuration.

Comment: I guess so. I'm sorry I can't help you right now, but please let me know if you found a solution.

Comment: @SventenHaaf, got it. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027260/nested-url-routing-using-react-router-and-webpack-dev-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by this solution in webpack config:

```
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true <-- this needs to be set to true
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027260/nested-url-routing-using-react-router-and-webpack-dev-server)