# Enable single page app react hot reload webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server, react-hot-loader

I have some problems setting up a single page react app using react router with the webpackdevserver. If I use browserhistory webpack has some problems when entering a nested route url (/client/view for example). This could be solved adding apiFallback but hot reload does still have a problem. It tries to load the hot-update.json file from the deep url (/client/view/hot-update.json) which does not exist and therefor fails and reloads the page. How can i tell hotreload to always load the hot-update.json from the base url (/)?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when using a `publicPath` other than `''`, which I solved by adding a proxy entry to the `devServer` options:

```
devServer: {
  // ... rest of options
  proxy: {
    '/myPublicPath/*': {
      target: 'http://localhost:8080/',
      pathRewrite: { '^/myPublicPath': '' },
  }
}
```

Other than that, make sure both `output.publicPath` and `devServer.publicPath` is set and equal.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. The dev server kept trying to load `bundle.js` from the directory relative to the url. My `publicPath` is `'/'`, and, unfortunately, the other answer did not help. I solved the issue like this:

```
  devServer: {   
    // ... other options 
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /^.*\/bundle\.js$/, to: '/bundle.js' },
      ]
    }
  }
```